# How do I select files in a bash script that do not have an extension?

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards

Let's say I have files xinitrc, alphabetsoup, ieat.pie in the current directory. Need a bash script to select only xinitrc and alphabetsoup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bash extended glob `+([^.])` will match files without any <kbd>.</kbd> in their name. It requires that you have not unset `shopt extglob` (on modern bash installations, it should be set by default). The pattern means:

> any number (but at least one) of characters other than <kbd>.</kbd>

You can put all the filenames in an array:

```
NO_EXTENSION=( +([^.]) )
```

You can print the filenames:

```
printf "%s\n" +([^.])
```

Or pass them all to a utility:

```
ls -- +([^.])
```

If you want them in variable but not an array, you need to be very sure that no file has whitespace in its name. If you are absolutely certain of this, you can do:

```
NO_EXTENSION=$(echo +([^.]))
```

The invocation of echo is necessary in order to get pathname expansion to happen, unlike in the array case. I strongly recommend using arrays for this sort of list, because you don't have to worry about special characters in the filenames.

Comment: I am trying to set a variable in a bash script. Such that `files=*.[nothing]`.

Comment: @multiphrenic: then the above will work.

Answer (score 5):

You can get a list of files without full stop in their names in the working directory
with:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name "*.*"
```

You can also have files which are `.file` under unix, if you want to match those and `file`, but not `file.ext` then you can use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name "*.*" -o -name ".*[^.]*"
```

Comment: You second one will include dot files that have at least one non-dot character. You need `\( -name '.?*' ! -name '.*.*' \)`.

Answer (score 3):

With the [`extglob` option](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion), you can match the complement of a pattern, i.e. the files whose name do not match the pattern. Files with an extensions are the ones that match `*.*`, so files with no extension in the current directory can be matched this way:

```
shopt -s extglob
somecommand !(*.*)
```

Note that dot files (files whose name begins with `.`) will not be included. If you want to match them as well and treat them as extensionless unless they contain a second `.`, you can use

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
somecommand !(*.*) .!(*.*)
```

or

```
shopt -s dotglob extglob
somecommand !(?*.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
$ ls | grep -v '\.'
```

Example:

```
$ ls
alphabetsoup  ieat.pie  xinitrc
$ ls | grep -v '\.'
alphabetsoup
xinitrc
```

Comment: [Never parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), it leads to trouble.

Comment: @terdon, if the intent is to store the list in a scalar variable anyway, that's better than the accepted solution that uses `echo`.